# Condensation on window frame in basement

Tags: basement, condensation

Freaking out here. Just had a second coat of mud put on the seams in the basement drywall. Went down to close up some of the vents because my guy is going to sand tomorrow and noticed a bunch of condensation on the windows frames.

I had vents added right in front of each window to properly heat the basement. Not sure if that is the cause. Or if it is just because of all the moisture from the mud added to the walls.

[image]

Any ideas on why? Or how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably seeing condensation of moisture from the drying of the drywall mud. Give it a few days before sounding the alarm bells.

If you are concerned about the short term humidity increase in that area you could consider running a dehumidifier in the room for a few days.

Comment: You must ventilate when taping, especially in winter. The gallons of water coming from the mud has to go somewhere. Run all bath fans full time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are finishing the basement to be used as living space, make sure that you provide the basement with enough supply and return registers. If the upstairs is 1000sq.ft. and the basement also has 1000sq. ft. then both areas will need approximately the same number of supply and return registers for those areas to be about the same temperature. Also, if you have A/C, make sure that the registers you use can be closed so that when the A/C runs the registers can be closed since a lot of the above floor's air will fall to the basement over-cooling that area. Most everyone makes the mistake of adding 1 or 2 registers and no returns and can't understand why the basement is so cold in the winter. The returns should be located at the floor level since that is where the cold air will be. The supply registers can be located anywhere.